Why am I getting "XMPPError: forbidden - auth [Access denied by service policy]" when registering a new user in ejabberd(23.10) using Smack(4.5)?
Problem Description:
I am trying to register a new user on an ejabberd server (23.0) hosted on an AWS instance using the Smack library (4.5). However, the registration fails with the following error:
XMPP error reply received from xxx.myejabberserver.com: XMPPError: forbidden - auth [Access denied by service policy]  

Server-Side Logs:
Here are the relevant logs from the ejabberd server:
2024-11-22 12:34:56.789 [info] <0.543.0>@ejabberd_listener:accept:363 (#Port<0.1234>) Accepted connection 198.51.100.45:12345 -> 203.0.113.20:5222
2024-11-22 12:34:56.890 [info] <0.543.0> Processing incoming stanza:
<iq type='set' id='reg1' to='xxx.myejabberserver.com'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:register'>
    <username>user102</username>
    <password>Abc@1234</password>
  </query>
</iq>

2024-11-22 12:34:56.891 [debug] <0.543.0> Checking ACL: 'register' for IP: 198.51.100.45
2024-11-22 12:34:56.891 [debug] <0.543.0> ACL 'register' matched: deny

2024-11-22 12:34:56.892 [info] <0.543.0> Outgoing stanza:
<iq type='error' id='reg1' to='198.51.100.45'>
  <error type='auth'>
    <forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    <text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Access denied by service policy</text>
  </error>
</iq>

#iq{id = <<"U94W7-7">>,type = error,lang = <<"en-US">>, ...}
<text xml:lang='en' xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Access denied by service policy</text>

Configuration Details:
These are the relevant parts of my ejabberd.yml configuration:
mod_register:
  access_from: "0.0.0.0"
  ip_access: "0.0.0.0"

acl:
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@my.domain.com"
  local:
    user_regexp: ""

access_rules:
  register:
    allow: all
allow_registration_ips:
  allow: all

What I Have Tried:

I verified that mod_register is enabled and allows all registrations.

I checked the acl and access_rules to ensure no restrictions on user registration.

Restarted the ejabberd service and tested again.

Searched for similar issues online and applied suggested fixes, but none worked.



mod_register:
  access_from: "0.0.0.0"
  ip_access: "0.0.0.0"

What documentation or tutorial did you read that recommends that configuration?
If you read the module documentation, those options do not accept such values.
